# How do I write a for loop within a function to pickup values within a csv?

Tags: python, function, api, csv, for-loop

I have a file called sampleweather100 which has Latitudes and longtidudes of addresses. If i manually type in these lats and longs under the location list function, I get the output I desire. However, I want to write a function where it pulls out the output for all rows of my csv without me manually entering it:

```
import pandas as pd
my_cities = pd.read_csv('sampleweather100.csv')
from wwo_hist import retrieve_hist_data

#lat = -31.967819
#lng = 115.87718
#location_list = ["-31.967819,115.87718"]

frequency=24
start_date = '11-JAN-2018'
end_date = '11-JAN-2019'
api_key = 'MyKey'

location_list = ["('sampleweather100.csv')['Lat'],('sampleweather100.csv')['Long']"]
hist_weather_data = retrieve_hist_data(api_key,
                                location_list,
                                start_date,
                                end_date,
                                frequency,
                                location_label = False,
                                export_csv = True,
                                store_df = True)
```

My function `location_list = ["('sampleweather100.csv')['Lat'],('sampleweather100.csv')['Long']"]` does not work. Is there a better way or a forloop that will fetch each rows lat and long into that `location_list` function:

Reprex of dataset:

```
 my_cities
Out[89]: 
                City        Lat        Long
0          Lancaster  39.754545  -82.636371
1             Canton  40.851178  -81.470345
2             Edison  40.539561  -74.336307
3       East Walpole  42.160667  -71.213680
4             Dayton  39.270486 -119.577078
5    Fort Wainwright  64.825343 -147.673877
6            Crystal  45.056106  -93.350020
7            Medford  42.338916 -122.839771
8      Spring Valley  41.103816  -74.045399
9          Hillsdale  41.000879  -74.026089
10           Newyork  40.808582  -73.951553
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way of building the list just does not make sense. You are using the filename of the csv, which is just a string and holds no reference to the file itself or the dataframe you have created from it.

Since you buildt a dataframe called `my_cities` from your csv using `pandas`, you need to extract your list of pairs from the dataframe `my_cities`:

```
location_list = [','.join([str(lat), str(lon)]) for lat, lon in zip(my_cities['Lat'], my_cities['Long'])]
```

This is the list you get with the above line using your sample dataframe:

```
['39.754545,-82.636371', '40.851178000000004,-81.470345',
 '40.539561,-74.33630699999999', '42.160667,-71.21368000000001',
 '39.270486,-119.577078', '64.825343,-147.673877', '45.056106,-93.35002',
 '42.338916,-122.839771', '41.103815999999995,-74.045399', 
 '41.000879,-74.026089', '40.808582,-73.951553']
```

Comment: I tried this but I only receive 1 ouput file. not all 10 ouputs for each latitude and longtidue

Comment: What do you mean by output file? This should produce a list, not a file.

Comment: within hist_weather_data the export_csv = True function converts the ouput into csv

Comment: I don't know how `wwo_hist` works, but I guess it creates a single csv with all the informations. Did you open the csv?

Comment: yeah it creates a single output csv for each lat and long.

Comment: Isn't that fine for you?

Comment: Yeah but thats not what I am receiving in my output. If it runs correctly i should receive 10 files, one for each.

Comment: Seems the API doesn't work that way. You get one file when you call `retrieve_hist_data`. Or you call the function multiple times in a loop (but I don't know if it is smart enough to name the files differently) or you read the file created by the function and the split it yourself. This deserve another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these to covert the dataframe into a list of comma-separated pairs:

```
location_list = [
    '{},{}'.format(lat, lon) 
    for i, (lat, lon) in my_cities.iterrows()
]
```

or

```
location_list = [
    '{},{}'.format(lat, lon) 
    for lat, lon in my_cities.values
]
```